# mysql: Remove records until

Tags: mysql

How can I delete all record, until some conditions happen? For example ordered by date. For example if conditions is non zero val, then first 2 records must be removed:

```
 val date
 0   10.10.2011
 0   11.10.2011
 3   12.10.2011
 0   13.10.2011
 1   14.10.2011
```

It can be done with 2 request, but I ask is there better solution.

Comment: if your conditions are subjected to change use procedures and supply parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use DELETE with a WHERE clause:

```
DELETE FROM `your_table` 
WHERE (val = 0 OR date < '2011-01-31')
```

Comment: But 'date' is unknown! So, this is not solution!